# enum members of members in C++, or alternative

Tags: c++, enums, member, variable-declaration

I want to use C++ to create an `enum` whose members have members.
I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766098/enum-constructors-creating-members-of-members), but that one dealt with D, not C++.

---

In Python, I can do this:

```py
class Product(enum.Enum):
    PHOTOSHOP = "Image editor.", 0
    FIREFOX = "Web browser.", 1
    NOTEPAD = "Text editor.", 2

    def __init__(self, description, num):
        self.description = description
        self.num = num
```

```py
>>> print(Product.PHOTOSHOP.description)
>>> "Image editor."
```

---

Java can do something like this:

```java
public enum Product {
    PHOTOSHOP("Image editor.", 0),
    FIREFOX("Web browser.", 1),
    NOTEPAD("Text editor.", 2);

    private final String description;
    private final int num;

    Product(String description, int num) {
        this.description = description;
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

---

Can I do this in C++?
If something to this effect can't be done in C++, what's a good alternative?

Comment: Yes you could use wrapper classes to emulate similar behavior, but not completely. Reason being you can't actually add member dynamically. It might be possible when combined with specially crafted pre-processor macros.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Pick one.

Comment: Your previous question in D ended up with the answer being a `tuple` you could do a similar thing with `std::pair` ...

Comment: @Olaf I had the impression C solution would also work in C++. Or is `enum` different between C and C++?

Comment: `enum` is not different, but you are solidly into the "use a custom type (ie. a struct) instead" territory, and that is different.

Comment: You got the answers already. A solution might exist for one of them but not both. All languages you cited are OOP languages, C is not (if you do not know this, perhaps you should never add the C tag). C and C++ are **different** languages.

Comment: There's any number of things you could do, here's a simplistic approach that doesn't guaruantee anything (like unique values...) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b79f84e25a43bf2

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you can't have multi-component enums in C++, though I don't claim to be an expert.

What you can do however is declare an enum and use it to look up strings in an array.

```
enum Product
{
    PHOTOSHOP = 0,
    FIREFOX,
    NOTEPAD,
    // must always be last
    PRODUCT_ENUM_SIZE
};

const char* Product_Descriptions[PRODUCT_ENUM_SIZE];
Product_Descriptions[PHOTOSHOP] = "Image Editor";
Product_Descriptions[FIREFOX] = "Web Browser";
Product_Descriptions[NOTEPAD] = "Text Editor";

std::cout << "Firefox product number: " << FIREFOX << ". Description: " << Product_Descriptions[FIREFOX] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

By going to a struct rather than an enum, you can accomplish something similar:

```
struct Product
{
    static constexpr struct type {const char* const description; const int num;}
        PHOTOSHOP{"Image editor.", 0},
        FIREFOX{"Web browser.", 1},
        NOTEPAD{"Text editor.", 2};
};
```

Unfortunately you can't use `std::string`, since it isn't a "literal" type, and thus not eligible for use in `constexpr` objects.

Another issue with this is that the type of the enumerands is `Product::type`, not just `Product`, and this will affect any code where you need to declare a variable.  It's just not possible to use inline definition and also have the same type for the items as the type that contains them.

Comment: This is a good answer, but having to explicitly declare the enumerand of each product increases the chance of accidentally adding duplicate values.

Comment: @Fibbles: The question wanted that (not that I can see any easy way to work around it)

Answer (score 1):

I realize it does not answer the question, but a full featured enum inevitably requires passing around a reference to a singleton instead of just a value (thus affecting spacial locality of the code). That would not be the C++ way.

The C++ way would be to only pay the price when you have to. For instance:

```
enum class X { ... };
char const* to_str(X x) { return lookup_value_in_static_map(x);}
X from_str(char const* v)
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, X x) { return out << to_str(x); }
```

The above can be made compile time friendly with a few easy tweaks if needed.